# Should breadcrumbs contain non-navigation elements

Tags: website-design, hyperlinks, breadcrumbs

I am working on an admin interface which uses a left menu as well as a breadcrumb at the top of the page.

I have items grouped into different levels in the menu as below:

[image: Side Menu]

In this menu, "Management", "Settings" and "Administration" aren't links, they're just used to group options together.

Now when I'm building the breadcrumb, is it best if the breadcrumb mirrors the menu as below?

[image: Breadcrumb with]

Or is it better to omit the non-linked item?

[image: Breadcrumb without]

Is having breadcrumb items without any navigation too jarring?

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to show only part of the content collapsing the breadcrumb as showed in this example: [Collapsed To Reveal Full Breadcrumbs On Hover](https://codemyui.com/collapsed-to-reveal-full-breadcrumbs-on-hover/)

[image]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/fraddski/pen/azjwev)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of navigation is to show a user where they're able to go, so you'll want to omit items that aren't a destination.

It might be simpler in this case to use a "< Back" link vs. a breadcrumb.